# Get a single doc inside subcollection by Id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

How can i get a single document data inside a subcollection by his id so i can show just a single workout info inside a component?

```
export default function WorkoutInfo(props){
const [workout,setWorkout]=useState({});
const [workoutName,setWorkoutName] = useState("");
const workoutsCollectionRef = collection(db,"users",props.userId,"workouts");

useEffect(()=>{
    const queryWorkouts = query(workoutsCollectionRef)
    const unsuscribe= onSnapshot(queryWorkouts,(snapshot)=>{
        let workout={};
        snapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
            if(doc.id==props.workotId)
                workout=({...doc.data(),id:doc.id});
        })
        setWorkout(workout);
    })

    return () => unsuscribe();
},[])}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what this code is supposed to do that isn't working the way you expect.  Be sure to include your debugging details, including any logs that you add that illustrate the problem.  We can't tell you how it's supposed to work - we need you to be specific about it. Right now what you have queries for all the documents in the subcollection and tries to pick out a single one.

Comment: I will point out also that we can't see the values of `props.userId` and `props.workotId`, so we really don't know what will happen when this runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `props.workotId` [sic] is the  the document ID of the workout document you want to load, you can [listen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to it with:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const documentRef = doc(workoutsCollectionRef, props.workotId);
    const unsubcribe= onSnapshot(documentRef,(doc)=>{
        setWorkout({...doc.data(),id:doc.id});
    })

    return () => unsubcribe();
},[])}
```